# How can I hide a function call from transpiled code using source maps?

Tags: javascript, source-maps

Let's say I have a language that looks like

```
print "Hello World"
```

which transpiles to

```
var $__Helpers = {
    print: function(s) {
        if (typeof s != 'string')
            throw new TypeError('String expected');
        console.log(s);
    }
};

$__Helpers.print("Hello World");
```

If a user of this language does

```
print 5
```

a TypeError will be thrown by `$__Helpers.print` saying "String expected".  I want the developer tools to show the `print 5` line as the originating call for this error.  I know how to get my source map to show a call stack that looks like

```
transpiled_script.js:2
original_script.os:1
```

where `transpiled_script.js:2` is the script and line number for the call to the `$__Helpers.print` function and `original_script.os:1` is the script and line number for the call to `print 5`.  I want to have the dev tools just ignore the top call to `transpiled_script.js` (which is only an implementation detail of my transpiler) and only show the call from the original script (which is the part that they should debug in their own script).

I clearly can't simply map `transpiled_script.js:2` to `original_script.os:1` because there could be multiple calls to `print` inside `original_script.os`, so it's not a 1 to 1 relationship.

Is there any way to do this?

(I am using escodegen to generate my source and my source map (escodegen uses the Node mozilla/source-map module), so having a way to tell escodegen or mozilla/source-map to do this would be ideal, but I can override escodegen's output if that's not possible.)

Comment: I might didn't get it all the way.. why don't you make a metadata map that holds the info and by its attribute on you stack display you decide what to display. something like { strack: {transpiled_script.js:2: {display:false}, original_script.os:1: {display: true}}

Comment: @arik I'm not creating my own devtools. It has to be compliant with the source maps that existing browser devtools read (particularly I care most about latest Chrome).

Answer (score 3):

You may split the trace and print the required lines of it

```
var $__Helpers = {
    print: function(s) {
        if (typeof s != 'string'){
            var err = new TypeError('String expected');
            var trace = err.stack.split('\n')
            console.error(trace[0]); // TypeError: string expected
            console.error(trace[2]); // the line who called the function, probably 
            //original_script.os:1, or whatever line number the call was from
            //quit the script

        }
        console.log(s);
    } };
```

EDIT: a better solution, is to replace the trace of the error, than throw it, the code now look like this:

```
var $__Helpers = {
    print: function(s) {
        if (typeof s != 'string'){
            var err = new TypeError('String expected: Got'+s);
            err.stack = err.stack.replace(/\n.*transpiled_script\.js.*?\n/g,"\n");
            throw err;

        }
        console.log(s);
    } };
```

this will work for errors in nested called  too.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I think it is a pretty good workaround suggestion.  I'm going to award you the bounty because I don't have any other contenders and you deserve it... However, it's not comprehensive.  What if the script I build is a library used by other people's code?  What if they pass in a callback to my code and their callback throws an error?  When their callback throws, my code will show up in the call stack, but I won't have a chance to filter the stack since they are originating the error...

Comment: So though I'll award you the bounty; I'm not going to accept this answer because it's not sufficient. I think a comprehensive answer is going to require this to be solved on the *source map* end.  Thanks again!

Comment: as far as i know most libraries show their calls in the trace, and in non type-safe languages (or not well documented libraries) i find it very useful during debugging.

Comment: the only way i see around this is too wrap any callback function with try .. catch block, not so beautiful but work